# How to concat two const char*?

Tags: c++

I am not able to concat two `const char*`.

I do the following:

```
const char* p = new char[strlen(metadata.getRoot())+strlen(metadata.getPath())];
strcat(const_cast<char*>(p),metadata.getRoot());
strcat(const_cast<char*>(p),metadata.getPath());

strcpy(const_cast<char*>(args2->fileOrFolderPath),p);

function(args2->fileOrFolderPath);
```

Now when I print the variable `args2->fileOrFolderPath` on the console then the correct output appears... But when I call a method with the variable as parameter, and work with the variable then I got a segmentation fault. What is the problem?

Comment: are you calling by value or by reference ? Did you try calling it with p ?

Comment: Why are you using `const char*` anyways? First, you should use `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`, second you can always convert to `const char*` when you eventually need it.

Comment: Btw, your code has a memory leak since you don't free `p`. It seems pointless allocating `p` anyway, you might just as well build the string directly into the memory pointed to by `args2->fileOrFolderPath`. If it's long enough, which you don't appear to check. The reason for using `std::string` is to save pages of code dealing with that kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
const char* p=new char[strlen(metadata.getRoot())+strlen(metadata.getPath())+1];
```

the length plus 1 to store '\0'.

2.

```
strcpy(const_cast<char*>(args2->fileOrFolderPath),p);
```

You can not guarantee `args2->fileOrFolderPath` 's length is longger than `strlen(p)`.

This works well

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void foo(const char*s){
    cout<<s<<endl;
}
int main(int argc,char*argv[]){
    const char* s1 = "hello ";
    const char* s2 = "world!";
    const char* p = new char [strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1];
    const char* s = new char [strlen(s1)+strlen(s2)+1];
    strcat(const_cast<char*>(p),s1);
    strcat(const_cast<char*>(p),s2);
    strcpy(const_cast<char*>(s),p);
    cout<<s<<endl;
    foo(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Tobi Weißhaar yeah ,the dest buffer can not be const ,because you are changing it .

Comment: What is args2->fileOrFolderPath ? Did you malloc enough memory for it ?

Comment: I solved the problem:

I simply did:

    char* p = new char[strlen(metadata.getRoot())+strlen(metadata.getPath())+1];
    strcat(p,metadata.getRoot());
    strcat(p,metadata.getPath());
    args2->fileOrFolderPath = p;

    function(args2->fileOrFolderPath);

and in the fucntion I delete the variable.

Answer (score 3):

I did not declare them like this but i know they have this information
So, I have this:

```
const char* ruta1 = "C:\\Users\\Deivid\\Desktop\\";
const char* ruta2 = "lenaGris.xls";
```

Then I used this for concatenation:

```
char * RutaFinal = new char[strlen(ruta1) + strlen(ruta2) + 1];
strcpy(RutaFinal, ruta1);
strcat(RutaFinal, ruta2);

printf(RutaFinal);
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer using std::string for this, but if you like char* and the str... functions, at least initialize p before using strcat:

```
*p = 0;
```

---

BTW:
using std::string, this would be:

```
std::string p = std::string(metadata.getRoot()) + metadata.getPath();
strcpy(const_cast<char*>(args2->fileOrFolderPath), p.c_str());

function(args2->fileOrFolderPath);
```

And you don't have to deallocate p somewhere.

Comment: @Toby: There is absolutely no reason to declare p as const, because you are trying to change it, so remove the const, but you really have to initialise p (by setting it to 0 or by using strcpy before using strcat).  BTW, is there any reason to have fileOrFolderPath const?

Comment: @Toby: When you say "this doesn't work", do you also mean the std::string solution?

Answer (score 1):

You have char pointers, pointing to char constants which can't be modified . What you can do is to copy your const char array to some char array and do  like this to concate const strings :

```
char result[MAX];   

strcpy(result,some_char_array); // copy to result array 
strcat(result,another_char_array); // concat to result array
```

Comment: @Tobi: strcpy starts writing to the first character of result.  strcat searches for the first occurrence of the null-character, so if you want to use strcat, you must first initialise result.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to include space for the null terminator, and the first parameter to `strcat` shouldn't be `const` as you're trying to modify the memory being pointed to.

You want to do something like this:

```
char * str1 = "Hello, ";
char * str2 = "World!\n";

char * buffer = malloc(strlen(str1) + strlen(str2) + 1);

strcpy(buffer, str1);
strcat(buffer, str2);

printf(buffer);
```

Which prints out "Hello, World!" as expected.

As for the error you're seeing when using a parameter, I've wrote some tests to see why it doesn't break when using a const local variable. While compiling using a `const char *` for the pointer I'm using as the target I get this warning:

```
./strings.c:10: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strcat’ discards qualifiers from pointer target type
```

As it states, const is discarded and it works as expected. However, if I pass a parameter which is a `const char *` pointer, then I get a bus error when trying to modify the buffer it writes to. I suspect what is happening is that it ignores the const on the argument, but it can't then modify the buffer because it's defined as const elsewhere in the code.

Comment: Shouldn't you use "calloc" or change first "strcat" to "strcpy"?

Comment: This is not C++ (malloc). Show C++